# z index of hidden div not allowing to drag?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div in my page

```
<div class="upper drag-support"  style="text-align:center;height:10000px; display: block;background-color:#e5ecec;right:0;left:0;top:0;position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:2000">
```

this will cover the whole area of the image, but i have made this div hidden by default using

```
$('.upper').hide();
```

But due to the zindex set to 2000 i am not able to drag items in the page.
if i change the z index it will work,

But i dont want to change z index, why its not working even it is hidden?
how can i fix this?

Comment: Did you try `pointer-events: none;` for that overlay `div`.?

Comment: no i cant use that, because i have a dragenter event wriiten for the div

Comment: in the `.upper` div.? then why are you trying to hide it.?

Comment: basically its for scrolling enhancemnet, when i dragover the upperdiv it will start scrolling the page. the height of the div is 200px only, for testing purpose i made it 10000

Answer (score 0):

You can change the z-index of the div using jQuery in code before hiding it.

```
$('.upper').css('z-index','1');
$('.upper').hide();
```

To set it back to 2000 use

```
$('.upper').css('z-index','2000');
```

Comment: tried but still not able to do ,  i have removed zindex, and while dragging i set to 2000.

Comment: Can you please create a working fiddle? @hilda_sonica_vish